# How to select data from data-frame in a specific manner using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new in python. I want to select data from the data frame in the following manner i.e.,

```
count
2
3
0
6
```

Here count is my column name and `2,3,0,6....`.etc is my row data.
S0 I want to select 1 to 13 rows data and then 2 to 14 rows data and so on till last data of dataset. So is there any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) to perform [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
for i in range(0,n):
    print(df[df.count.between(1+i,13+i)]) 
#[df[df.count.between(1+i,13+i)] for i in range(0,n)] #to keep in a list
```

---

Or by the `Index`:

```
for i in range(0,n):
    print(df[1+i:13+i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using .iloc and loc:

```
Rows = [5, 10] 
Columns = ["Column1", "Column2"] 
df.loc[Rows, Columns]
```